# How a textarea can display an svg file

Tags: php, html, css

Trying to insert some svg's in my chat app. If I use them as PHP files, it's ok they will display in the `chat#div` but in the text area it's the full code of the svg's. When I'm trying to display them as svg the only thing I can see in the chat is this `[object XMLDocument]` both in text area and in `#div`

here's the code for the textarea

```
<textarea id="comment" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 10px; box-shadow: 
 inset 0 -15px 35px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); height: 40px; overflow: auto; 
  pointer-events: all;">
</textarea>
```

and here is the javascript for the svg

```
function test(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"emoticons/cloudda3.svg",
        success:function(result){
            $("#comment").val(result);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Isn't textarea only for text?

Comment: well yes it's true, but I sicking a way to use svg's there. Cannot type to text area when a huge code appears there. Trying to make it a div. Is there any way for this?

Comment: Use `<div contenteditable=true><svg>...</svg></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `div` Element has a `contenteditable` attribute, setting it to `true` will allow the user to enter and modify the data in the `div`. The best thing: the `div` can contain rich text including images.

```css
.textarea {
  font-family: monospace;
  outline: none;
  background: #efefef;
  border: #888 1px solid;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 9pt;
}

img {
  height: 9pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/90/Perry-miniature-donkey-in-Palo-Alto-CA-2016.jpg/800px-Perry-miniature-donkey-in-Palo-Alto-CA-2016.jpg" />
</div>
```

> **Note:** The `<img>` tag in the `<div>` can be replaced with any valid image or SVG.

As a sidenote, @emaillenin is correct in saying that `textareas` are only for text. Also I'm noticing you using the `val` function to insert, that would mean that the value of the element is updated, not it's innerHTML. This would result in a behaviour similar to what you are seeing now. If you want to get just the text from the div, use the `text` function.

Comment: well it works if I only want to enter the code into the text area. The only problem is that the code is huge. Is there anyway to call the svg's like for example [:cloudda] and watch this in the text area?

Comment: Adding the SVG programatically ist entirely possible, it is exactly the same as regular HTML except that you can edit the text inside the div. So if you want to add something to it, you'd use a querySelector or whatnot

Comment: found the way thanks all of you!  function test(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudda3.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val('<img src="emoticons/cloudda3.svg"><br>');
            }})
           }

Comment: Hey that's AWESOME! Glad I could help